# Построчная запись и удаление из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим в поле БД надо поместить список `id` пользователей, для этого, вероятнее всего, надо юзать массив с разделителями.

Но как дописывать в этот список, и удалять по одному `id`?

Comment: См. "нормальные формы" в любом учебнике по реляционным базам. Если кратко - массив с разделителями - неправильный способ и ничего кроме тормозов для mysql и кучи головной боли для вас это не даст.

Comment: делайте связь один ко многим, id пользователей вписывайте не в одно поле с разделителем, а ссылайтесь на вторую таблицу с этими id

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос с отличным ответом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853484/Как-сделать-выборку-из-mysql-таблицы-по-полю-с-несколькими-значениями