# Как сделать выборку из Mysql таблицы по полю с несколькими значениями?

Tags: php, mysql

Как быть, есть три таблицы
**1. cities**

```
id | name
--------------
1  | Moskow
2  | Kirow
3  | Orel
....
```

**2. categories**

```
id | name
--------------
1  | name1
2  | name2
3  | name3
...
```

**3. И есть третья таблица - список компаний:**

```
id  |    name   |  cities_id   |    categories_id
----------------------------------------------------
1   | alpha     | 1,2,5,18     | 3,76,78
2   | betta     | 2,14,31      | 13,60,75
3   | gamma     | 1,17,19      | 95,101
....
```

Вопрос следующий:
**Как удобно делать выборку компаний по городу, категории, городу и категории вместе, если каждая компания может работать в нескольких городах и выполнять несколько категорий работ?**

варианты из 1930 городов, 285 категорий.

Раньше я использовал:

- FILD_IN_SET() но сейчас значений больше чем 64 и этот вариант не годится.

  - ENUM тоже не получается, так как поля cities_id и categories_id могут содержать сразу несколько значений
  - переводил все это в многомерный массив потом на php искал.
  - делал всякие WHERE  cities_id LIKE '%,5,%'   OR  cities_id LIKE '5,%'  OR  cities_id LIKE '%,5' (как и варианты с дописыванием в поле в начале и конце запятыt, для сокращения количества OR).
  - еще советовали связать таблицы, но как это сделать когда в cities_id и categories_id несколько значений, да и как потом выбирать с учетом этих связей, я не сумел разобраться (не нашел примеров нормальных, так как не знал что даже искать, да и то ли это, что нужно?)

**Есть ли красивые решения которые используются в профессиональной среде, или все так и лепят как я? 
Разъясните, гуру, очень хочу разобраться.**

Comment: Если бы вы использовали нормальные формы, то не пришлось сталкиваться с такими дикими запросами. Попробуйте перевести таблицу со списком компаний вдве таблицы в НФ-2

Comment: Не совсем вас понял. Что именно вы рекомендуете хранить в двух таблицах со списками компаний. Что в одной, что во второй? Поясните.

Comment: Функции `FILD_IN_SET()` - не существует. Существует функция  [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), у которой нет ограничения на количество значений (есть только ограничение на размер пакета данных, но он очень большой). Но это костыль, пусть и работающий. Решение, несомненно, в нормализации.

Comment: @Akina
Да вы правы я опечатался.  FIND_IN_SET() имелось ввиду. Какой тип поля вы рекомендуете для него использовать?

Comment: добавьте таблицы CompanyCities и CompanyCategories

Comment: *Какой тип поля вы рекомендуете для него использовать?* Странный вопрос... принимаемые функцией параметры должны иметь строковый тип для исключения неявного приведения типа. Так что BLOB для второго параметра лучше не использовать. И первый, если он не строковый, приводить к строке явно.

Comment: Ваше приложение находится в этапе разработки или уже готовое и работает ? Если на этапе разработки, то избавьтесь и не когда больше не используйте в одной колонке списки айдишников, это же просто ужас, вы запросы с такой структурой таблиц не когда не оптимизируете

Comment: @madfan41k Можно ссылки на примеры, где это объясняется, или хотя бы тут напишите как это должно быть. Пока для меня звучит дико, чтобы создать отдельную таблицу где просто будут перечислины варианты пересечений компаний и городов а так же компаний и категорий. Так реально делают? Приведите пример запроса к такой структуре, я не совсем понимаю.

Неужеди код и правда будет меньше, чем с теми же: WHERE cities_id LIKE '%,5,%' OR cities_id LIKE '5,%' OR cities_id LIKE '%,5'

Или вы под оптимизацией имеете ввиду что то еще? Поясните конкретно что, потому что я хочу понять.

Comment: @Akina что прям  FIND_IN_SET() проходится по полю varchar где через запятую указаны значения?

Comment: Какая Вам разница, как именно сервер это делает? Но внешне да, всё выглядит именно так.

Comment: *где это объясняется* "Нормальные формы" - в любом учебнике или поисковике. Начать можете с [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Comment: @Akina  FIND_IN_SET()  в простом строковом поле и вправду сработал, благодарю, думаю это хороший вариант, чтобы не городить доп таблицы.

Comment: *думаю это хороший вариант, чтобы не городить доп таблицы.* Пока в таблице мало записей, это верно. Низкая производительность функции - не проблема. Но чем больше массив данных, тем больше будет проблем - а на готовом продукте менять неэффективную структуру будет весьма непросто.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

таблица городов

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

таблица категорий

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
      `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

таблица компаний

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
      `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

смежная таблица городов компаний

```
CREATE TABLE `company_city` (
      `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `company_id` int(11)
      `city_id` int(11)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

смежная таблица категорий компаний

```
CREATE TABLE `company_category` (
      `id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `company_id` int(11)
      `category_id` int(11)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

И запрос на выборку

```
select
  a_company.name,
  group_concat(DISTINCT a_city.name SEPARATOR ', ') as company_cities,
  group_concat(DISTINCT a_category.name SEPARATOR ', ') as company_categories
from a_company
left join a_company_city on a_company_city.company_id = a_company.id
left join a_company_category on a_company_category.company_id = a_company.id
left join a_category ON a_category.id = a_company_category.category_id
left join a_city ON a_city.id = a_company_city.city_id
GROUP BY a_company.name
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую в этом разобраться, но это явно длиннее чем LIKE '%,5,%' или FIND_IN_SET. Хотелось бы понять еще преимущества такого решения.

Comment: Преимущества в нормализации данных, запросы будут выполняться быстрее, потмоу что по id искать быстрее, чем LIKE. С такой архитектурой БД действительно какие угодно запросы возможны.

Comment: к тому же like не использует индекс

Comment: @user281850 Почитайте  https://habr.com/post/254773/ там пример на подобие вашего

Comment: @madfan41k спасибо за ссылку.